# python 2.x zlib.decompress data from mysql

Tags: python

Can I decompress data in python that compressed from mysql?

mysql 5.6

```
select to_base64(compress("test"));
```

result from mysql

```
BAAAAHicK0ktLgEABF0BwQ==
```

python to decompress

```
>>> import zlib
>>> import base64
>>> s = "BAAAAHicK0ktLgEABF0BwQ=="
>>> zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

I checked the [zlib manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress) I don't know why it's giving the error?

**Solution**
I found solution from my friend.

```
ss = base64.b64decode(s)
zlib.decompress(ss[4:])
```

Answer (score -1):

I expect that mysql isn't compressing this the right way (or not with zlib, anyway)

```
import zlib
import base64
print(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress('test'))) # 'test'.encode() on Python3
```

Produces:

```
'eJwrSS0uAQAEXQHB'
```

Comment: there is less information about mysql compress, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress

Comment: What do you get back just `select compress("test")`?

Comment: I use `select compress("test")` it gives me binary code `x+I-.]Á`, I did the length `select length(compress("test"));`, it gives me 16, it seems compress function is different in mysql, while python gives me 12 with `>>> len(zlib.compress("test"))`